# Summation of quotient and quotient of summation

Tags: inequality

I have $P_1, P_2, P_3, \dotsc, P_n, S_1, S_2, S_3, \dotsc, S_n$.

Is it always true that:
$$
\frac{P_1+P_2+P_3+\dotsb+P_n}{S_1+S_2+S_3+\dotsb+S_n} \leq \frac{\frac{P_1}{S_1}+\frac{P_2}{S_2}+\frac{P_3}{S_3}+\dotsb+\frac{P_n}{S_n}}{n}
$$

Comment: Are there any conditions on $P_k$'s and $S_k$'s, or are they allowed to be negative?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Take $n=2, P_1=3,P_2=1,S_1=3,S_2=2$. Then $\frac{P_1+P_2}{S_1+S_2}=\frac{4}{5}$, but $\frac{\frac{P_1}{S_1}+\frac{P_2}{S_2}}{2}=\frac{3}{4}<\frac{4}{5}$.